# How does iTunes movie DRM work?

Tags: itunes, drm

Is a movie locked to the computer I originally download it on? Is it locked to my iTunes account, and I can play it with any computer where that account is active? What?

I can't seem to find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are locked to the account they were purchased under.  Any machine that is authorized with that account can play that file.